# Video viewing and storage behaviour on tablets

Tags: video, tablet

I am looking into the behaviours of people viewing videos offline on their tablets.

On average, how many videos do people typically store in their tablets and how long do they tend to keep it there?

The tablet can support expandable memory storage e.g SD card.

Comment: Depends on the storage of the tablet ?

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this since it would depend on the use case of the tablet, does the user use it as an entertainment device or does it he use it for office work. You need to be more specific about your user base since that would affect results

Comment: It would be targeted towards a personal entertainment device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that [tablets don't leave home](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/google_tablets_are_for_fun_laptops_are_for_work_st.php) too often.

Therefore, I expect the number of *offline videos* to be low: I mean, if around 80% of the time, the tablet is at home, why to bother? You can use the high-speed network your own house is connected to.

If tablets don't leave home, the only time I see it viable to store offline videos is on long journeys. I expect people to pack one or two films they want to watch, perhaps a few episodes of their favourite series.

Also, it's inconvenient to upload movies to an iPad from the laptop. I've never bought a TV-show from iTunes though...

When I was traveling between Berlin and Budapest on a monthly basis by train (much better than airplane: comfortable bed, electricity, departs and arrives to the heart of the cities), I used the iPad as the travel device: although, honestly, I mostly read books and/or listen to music.

On everyday commute, based on the statistics, smartphones are the way to go: even if they offer smaller screen, they're less bulky.

But as samsung is definitely blurring the line between a tablet and a smartphone, with offerings on every two inch (3", 4", 5", 7", 10"...), we can't know exactly...